# How to use view-i18n to translate url parameters during route generation in nuxt.config

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I'm working on a multilingual website project for a real estate agency, I used the project below to make the translations everything works well, the last step is to translate the parameters of the dynamic urls during the route generation

https://github.com/paulgv/nuxt-i18n-routing

But i do not know how to use view-i18n during route generation, can you help me ?

Here is a code snippet that I would like to use :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

import { ROUTES_ALIASES, DEFAULT_LOCALE, I18N } from '~/config'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

export default ({ app, store }) => {

    app.i18n = new VueI18n({
        // fallbackLocale: DEFAULT_LOCALE,
        messages: I18N,
      lazy: true,
      langDir: 'lang/',
      parsePages: false,
      pages: ROUTES_ALIASES
        // silentTranslationWarn: true
    })
    app.i18n.locale = store.state.i18n.currentLocale

    app.i18n.path = (link) => {
        console.log(link)
        if (app.i18n.locale === app.i18n.fallbackLocale) {
          return `/${link}`;
        }

    return `/${app.i18n.locale}/${link}`;
  }
}
```

I would like to call **app.i18n.t**('entitie.slug') into nuxt.config.js :

```
generate: {
   routes: function () {
      let results = axios.get(process.env.BASE_URL +  '/entities')
          .then((response) => {
            return response.data.map((entitie) => {
              return {
                route: '/en/myurl/' + app.i18n.t(entitie.slug)
              }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally chose a not really binding solution, my translation system generates specific files for slugs

```
import en from './lang/translations/slug/en.json'
```

The translation becomes simply a key / value replacement

> I would like to do that "route: '/en/myurl/' + **en[entity.slug]**"

```
import en from './lang/translations/slug/en.json'

... some code

generate: {
   routes: function () {

      ... some code

      let results = axios.get(process.env.BASE_URL +  '/entities')
          .then((response) => {
            return response.data.map((entity) => {
              return {
                route: '/en/myurl/' + en[entity.slug]
              }
            })
        })

      ... some code

    }
}
```